# rpy2 conversion to pandas DataFrame returns numpy recarray instead of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rpy2

I am trying to convert an R data frame into a python using `rpy2`

```
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
                smogned = ro.conversion.rpy2py(smogned)
print('after pandas2ri')            
print(type(smogned))
print(smogned.shape)
print(smogned.dtype)
```

which gives me the following

```
after pandas2ri
<class 'numpy.recarray'>
(7412,)
(numpy.record, [('WS', '<f8'), ('WS_1', '<f8'), ('WS_2', '<f8'), ('WS_3', '<f8'), ('WS_4', '<f8'), ('WS_5', '<f8'), ('RH', '<f8'), ('RH_1', '<f8'), ('RH_2', '<f8'), ('RH_3', '<f8'), ('RH_4', '<f8'), ('RH_5', '<f8'), ('TA', '<f8'), ('TA_1', '<f8'), ('TA_2', '<f8'), ('TA_3', '<f8'), ('TA_4', '<f8'), ('TA_5', '<f8'), ('gridMET_ETr', '<f8'), ('Site_Id_1', '<f8'), ('Site_Id_2', '<f8'), ('Site_Id_3', '<f8'), ('Site_Id_4', '<f8'), ('Site_Id_5', '<f8'), ('Site_Id_6', '<f8'), ('Vegetation_1', '<f8'), ('Vegetation_2', '<f8'), ('Vegetation_3', '<f8'), ('Month_1', '<f8'), ('Month_2', '<f8'), ('Month_3', '<f8'), ('Month_4', '<f8'), ('LE_bowen_corr_mm_', '<f8')])
```

Also its important to note that my data has 33 columns while the one returned is of shape `(7412,)`. What should I do to make it a pandas data frame ?? Also I wish it can return directly the dataframe as pandas because I dont want to end up cconverting the recarray into a numpy array and the numpy array to a pandas because when you do

```
pd.DataFrame(data=yourdata, columns=[...])
```

you have to specify the columns in the same order I have the `smogned` dataframe columns returned and I cannot control this at the moment

**Information**

- numpy version 1.16.4
- pandas version 0.20.3
- rpy2 version 3.2.6

Comment: what's `smogned.dtype`?  Does `DataFrame(smogned)` work?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you so much, converting it explicitly to ```pandas.DataFrame``` made it work!! I mentioned you in my answer and I updated my question with adding ```smogned.dtype```'s output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hpaulj, I fixed this by converting the 'recarray' to a pandas DataFrame explicitly:

```
smogned = pd.DataFrame(smogned)
```

Although its still weird for me why is it returning a `recarray`